# What is the graph of the polar equation theta = pi?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

The question exactly goes like the title. I'm thinking that it's a point on the 3.14, but as I'm typing this I realize that I'm wrong and now I'm out of clues (Google didn't help). Please enlighten me.

Comment: A straight line corresponding to an angle $\pi$ from the positive $x$-axis.

Comment: So you mean.. Snap, I didn't get it. Is it a straight line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\theta=k$ would be a line passing through the origin, with slope $\tan(k)$.

So here, the slope would be $\tan(\pi)$,  but only in the backward direction, that is the the negative $x$ axis in this case.

Here is a picture, showing two graphs. $\color{red}{Red}$ for $2\pi/3$ and $\color{blue}{blue}$ for $\theta=\pi$

[image]

Comment: If I am interpreting this correctly, the graph is a straight line from the origin/pole, going to the left?

Comment: @Gannicus see diagram.

Comment: Cool cool cool. Thanks!

Comment: @Gannicus you're welcome. :) Credits: [graph.tk](http://graph.tk/)